# PostgreSQL substring and regexp_replace fill with zeros

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following entries in `build` column:

```
4.4_sometext
4.9_sometext
4.11_sometext
```

I have tried these 2 methods:

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace(build, '_.*$', '') AS build
  FROM tableX 
 ORDER BY build
```

and

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(build FOR POSITION('_' IN build) -1) AS build 
  FROM tableX 
 ORDER BY build
```

Both ways are returning me the following:

```
4.40
4.90
4.11
```

so it's extracting the number correctly BUT padding it with zeros on the right when there is only 1 decimal, which changes a bit the initial string I had.

Is it possible to make it keep the original number of decimals?

UPDATE: I am using this queries inside Grafana v9.4.7 with a bar chart.

Comment: The queries you have shown will most certainly **not** add the trailing zero. https://dbfiddle.uk/ALB4gE1-

Comment: Your code works: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZE4pKVXC. Probably there is something else in your query that you are not showing and that is causing the problem.

Comment: Well, I forgot to say that I am using this queries inside Grafana. Maybe it's Grafana which is doing this magic...